# msys2 no black window

Tags: windows, terminal, msys2

[My screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO5BU.png)

How can I create a launcher for a program (or a script) on MSYS2 that does not show me the black window of the terminal?

My link:

```
msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64 -c  /c/myfolder/program.exe
```

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-01/msg00225.html

Comment: My executable is already compiled with the -mwindows flag and if I launch it from the folder with all dependencies no black window opens. In this case instead I want to start the executable from a Windows link, inside msys2 environment

Comment: The subsystem option is important to tell the linker that it is not a console mode app.  It is not clear to me why you think you need an msys2 environment, programs built with mingw need no help.  So don't run msys2.

Comment: Yes, but It would be very useful for me to start graphic scripts (such as python + gtk) from link windows. Without showing the user the unpleasant black window of the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a program in the MSYS2 environment without showing a window, you should right-click on your Desktop or somewhere else in Windows Explorer, select "New", select "Shortcut", and then enter something like this for the shortcut target:

```
C:\msys64\usr\bin\mintty.exe -w hide /bin/env MSYSTEM=MINGW64 /bin/bash -lc /c/path/to/your_program.exe
```

Note that there are 4 paths in here.  The path to `mintty` and `your_program.exe` are absolute paths that you will need to adjust.  The paths to `env` and `bash` are relative to your MSYS2 installation directory.  Note also that the first path must be a standard Windows path, since Windows expects that when it is running a shortcut.

### Explanation

It might seem odd to use `MinTTY` for this, but the first program we launch needs to be *some* program that was compiled for the Windows subsystem (`-mwindows` option to GCC), or else Windows will automatically start a new console when we run the program.  We pass the `-w hide` option to MinTTY to tell it not to actually show its own window.  Everything after that option is interpreted by `MinTTY` as a command to run.

So MinTTY will run `/bin/env` from the MSYS2 distribution and pass the remainder of the arguments on to it.  This is a handy utility that is actually a standard part of Linux as well as MSYS2.  It sets the `MSYSTEM` environment variable to `MINGW64` (which is important later) and then it runs `/bin/bash` with the remainder of the command-line arguments.  The `MSYSTEM` variable selects which of the three MSYS2 environments to use, and the value values for it are `MSYS2`, `MINGW32`, or `MINGW64`.

We pass `-l` to Bash so that it acts as a login script, and runs certain startup scripts.  In particular, the `/etc/profile` script from MSYS2 is essential because it looks at the `MSYSTEM` environment variable, sees that it is `MINGW64`, and then sets a bunch of other environment variables (e.g. `PATH`) to give you the MinGW 64-bit shell environment, or some different environment if you changed `MSYSTEM`.

Finally, we pass the name of your program as the main argument to `bash`, so it will run that program after running the initialization scripts.

Comment: Thanks it works, but I had to modify "bash -l myprog.exe" in "bash -lc myprog.exe"